# The smallest positive integer in the set $\{24u+60v+200w : u,v,w \in \Bbb Z\}$is given by which of the following number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on the following problem:

> The smallest positive integer in the set $\{24u+60v+200w : u,v,w \in \Bbb Z\}$is given by which of the following number?
>
> The options are: $2,4,6,24$.

Since $24u+60v+200w=4(6u+15v+50w)$, I think the answer is between 4 and 24. Can someone explain it?

Comment: The answer should be the greatest common divisor of $24, 60, 200$.

Comment: ans. is gcd of $24,60,200$ because gcd can be express unique way if d is gcd of $24,60,200$ then $d=24x+60y+200z$ where $x,y,z$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464156/what-is-the-smallest-positive-integer-in-the-set-24x60y2000z-mid-x-y-z-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: It shouldn't be too hard to convince yourself (or even prove) that the greatest common divisor of 24, 60 and 200 must also divide $24u+60v+200w$ for any $u,v,w\in \mathbb{Z}$ and in fact we can find $u,v$ and $w$ for any multiple of the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The greatest common divisor of $6$ and $15$ is $3,$ so we can get any integer multiple of $3$ from $6u+15v$ by choosing appropriate $u,v$. Now put $w=2,$ and choose an appropriate integer multiple of $3$ for $6u+15v$ to be.

More generally, given integers $n_1,n_2,...,n_k,$ the least positive integer in the set of sums $n_1m_1+n_2m_2+...+n_km_k$ (with the $m_j\in\Bbb Z$) will be the greatest common divisor of $n_1,n_2,...,n_k$.

Answer (score 0):

![least positive intager.....]

[image]

Comment: Please type it up instead of posting an image to keep the site searchable!