# what is the smallest positive integer in the set $\{24x+60y+2000z \mid x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I cant understand how to do it please help me. Thanks in advance my question is  what is the smallest positive integer in the  set   $\{24x+60y+2000z \mid x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$! its options are given $2,4,6,24$

Comment: why can't we put $x=y=z=1?$

Comment: Well @labbhattacharjee, because $\;x=y=-10\;,\;z=1\;$ gives a much smaller positive integer (I'm guessing +ve is a sad way to write "positive"...)

Comment: here x,y,z are any integers which may be +ve as well as -VE

Comment: please someone help me

Answer (score 8):

As $(24,60)=12,$

$24a+60b=12(2a+5b)$ will be divisible by $12$  for integers $a,b$

Using Bézout's [Lemma](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma)/[identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), we can find integers $x,y$ such that $24x+60y=12$

In fact $60(1)+24(-2)=12$

Now, $(12,2000)=4,$ we can find integers $p,q$ such that $12p+2000q=4$

By actual division $2000=167\cdot12-4\implies  167\cdot12-2000=4$

$$\implies 167\{60(1)+24(-2)\}-2000=4$$

$$\implies 167\cdot60+24(-2\cdot167)+2000(-1)=4$$

This is the smallest as $24x+60y+2000z=4(6x+15y+500z)$ will always be divisible by $4$ for integers $x,y,z$

Comment: You should add, why there is no smaller solution.

Comment: @Tomas,I was on my way of adding that

Answer (score 6):

The set in question is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence generated by a single element $c \in \mathbb{N}$, which is also the smallest positive integer in the set. This element must be a common divisor of 24, 60, and 2000 (since each of those elements is in this set). It is not too hard to see that $c$ must be the greatest common divisor of all these three numbers, which is 4.

Comment: This is a nice, short and elegant way to do it. I'm upvoting it in spite of the fact that it'd be nicer to have an explanation slightly more developed (not much) for the OP's sake (for example, the given set is in fact $\,c\Bbb Z=4\Bbb Z\;$ and thus is trivial to see the least positive integer in in it is $\;4\;$ . +1

Answer (score 5):

$$24x+60y+2000z=4(6x+15y+500z)$$ Now, $$\gcd(6,15,500)=1\Rightarrow 6x+15y+500z=1$$ for some $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}$ by using the generalized Bezout's identity. Hence $4$ is the answer.

In general the minimum positive integer value that the set $\displaystyle \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx_k\big|x_k\in\mathbb{Z},1\le k\le n\right\}$ can give is $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots\ ,a_n)$.

Comment: Very nice indeed. +1

Answer (score 0):

Bézout's theorem about G.C.D answers your question I think:

Definition: We say $d=\gcd(a,b,c)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$,$b$ and $c$ if and only if the following holds:

1- $d>0$ 
2- $d|a$ , $d|b$ and $d|c$ 
3- If $e|a$ , $e|b$ and $e|c$ then $d|e$

Now we prove the existence of $\gcd(a,b,c)$ for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ using Bézout's theorem:

We claim that $d= \min\{ ax+by+cz>0: x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$:

It's clear that that $S=\{ ax+by+cz>0: x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z} \} \neq \emptyset$. Because either $a.1+b.0+c.0$ or $a.(-1)+b.0+c.0$ is positive and hence is in $S$. Therefore, $S$ is a non-empty subset of natural numbers and by using the [well-ordering principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) $S$ has a least positive element. set $d=\min(S)$. We claim that d satisfies all of the properties of $\gcd(a,b,c)$:

1) $d>0$ is trivial by the definition of $S$.

2) We claim that $d|a$, the same technique could be used to prove that $d|b$ and $d|c$

Using Euclid's division algorithm(theorem) we know that $\exists q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=qd+r$ where $0 \leq r < d$

But $d \in S$ therefore $\exists x_0,y_0,z_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d=a.x_0 + b.y_0 + c.z_0$. Therefore $a =q(a.x_0 + b.y_0 + c.z_0) + r \implies 0 \leq r = (1-qx_0)a + (-qy_0)b+(-qz_0)c \in S$. If $r>0$ then $r<d$ contradicts that $d = \min(S)$. Thefore $r=0$ and $a=qd$ which means $d|a$. You can similarly show $d|b$ and $d|c$.

3) if $e|a$ , $e|b$ and $e|c$ then $e|a.x_0+b.y_0+c.z_0, i.e. $e|d$

This proves that $d= \min\{ ax+by+cz>0: x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is equal to $\gcd(a,b,c)$. Therefore, all you need to do is to calculate $\gcd(a,b,c)$ and you can do that using Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1159482/242) for a more conceptual way to present the proof.