# Number theoritic question

Tags: number-theory

the smallest no of this set is $\{24x+60y+2000z: x,y, z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.and answer option is 2/4/6/24.. i tri this problem to putting the different valus of x,y,z. but i feel this not a right way. any one can help me?

Comment: You mean the smallest positive integer right ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464156/what-is-the-smallest-positive-integer-in-the-set-24x60y2000z-mid-x-y-z-in

Comment: I would guess the smallest number is somewhere around $-\infty$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\gcd(24,60,2000)=4$$
hence by the [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) there's $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z$ such that
$$24x+60y+2000z=4$$