# What is the smallest positive integer of the form $30x+6y+10z$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

I am trying to find the smallest positive integer of the form

$30x+6y+10z$, where $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}$

However, I do not know where to start. Hints or answers are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464156/what-is-the-smallest-positive-integer-in-the-set-24x60y2000z-mid-x-y-z-in

Comment: Hint: $30\cdot 0 + 6\cdot 2 +10\cdot (-1) = 2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:* The integer has to be even (can you see why?). $6$ yes. Can you get $4$ or $2$? If you can generate $2$ you're done.

Comment: I can see why it is even. I can set $x,z=0$ and that is a good enough answer? To get $4$ or $2$ would I use modular arithmetic?

Comment: The integer has to be even because the expression equals $2(15x + 3y + 5z)$, twice an integer is even.

As for generating $4$ or $2$, nothing that fancy is needed. Try some values of $x, y, z$

Comment: In general, could I take the "equation" modulo the gcd and if it equals $0$ that is the answer?

Comment: @SeanC: $10+6=16$ and $16\cdot2=32$ and $32-30=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbf Z$ is a PID, it is the gcd of 30, 6 and 10 — 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ The set $\rm\,S\,$ of integers of form $\rm\,a_1\,x_1 + \cdots + a_k x_k,\ x_i\in \mathbb Z,\,$ is closed under subtraction so, by [this Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242), every positive $\rm\,n\in S\,$ is divisible by $\rm\,d = $ least positive $\rm\in S.\,$  Now $\rm\,a_i\in S$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\rm d\mid a_i,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,d\,$ is a *common* divisor of all $\rm\,a_i,\,$ necessarily *greatest*: $\rm\ c\mid a_i$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\mid d = a_!\,x_1\!+\!\cdots\!+\!a_k x_k$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\le d.$

**Remark** $\ $ This is the general form of [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

See that $30 - 10 - 3\cdot 6 = 2 (= 2\cdot 10 - 3\cdot 6 = 2\cdot 6 - 10)$.
Also note that in general there always exists an integer linear combination of $\{x,y,z\}$ such that
$$\lambda_1 x+ \lambda_2 y + \lambda_3 z = \gcd(x,y,z)$$
Since $\gcd(30,10,6) = 2 \ne 1$ we know that $2$ is in fact the smallest possible integer. $\gcd(x,y,z)$ will always be the least positive integer of that form in general, this is known as [Bézout's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_three_or_more_integers).

Comment: There's an even easier solution for $2$

Comment: @SimonS $2\cdot 10 - 3\cdot 6$, but that's not "easier" in any way, huh?

Comment: @AlexR: Arguable. But there's an even easier one.

Comment: So the gcd is always the lowest positive integer of that form?

Comment: @SeanC Yes. It is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What combiniation are you thinking of?

Comment: I'm thinking of $2\cdot 6 - 10 $

Comment: @SeanC: Yes, that's [Bézout's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: This is news to me! Thanks!